# Ushpizin in the Rain

Tags: minhag, sukkot, meal-seudah, weather

Does one say Ushpizin if one is eating inside a house and not in the Sukkah due to heavy rain? Is Ushpizin about inviting the guest to the sukkah, or is it about inviting to the se'udah, where ever it is on Sukkot?

(H/T My Dad)

Comment: Great question! The source for the custom, Zohar 3:103b, says that Rav Hamenunah Saba would stand at the entrance of his Sukkah to invite the Ushpizin. Perhaps it's worth taking a closer look there.

Comment: From much of the language that I saw in the long intro to Ushpizin, it seems that this is specific for the Succah. Logically, we eat in our homes throughout the year. If it were an invitation to just the meal, then why aren't we saying Ushpizin during Pesach?

Comment: but we say azamin l'seudati -- I invite to my MEAL, not to my Sukkah.

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean by "say ushpizin". Ushpizin are guests that visit you on sukos. see here... http://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/571505/jewish/The-Ushpizin.htm

Comment: @DanF I'm not sure if that was a rhetorical question, but the Zohar there seems to be talking about an expectation that we share our bounty with others - especially people lacking bounty of their own - which in turn impresses the _n'vi'im_ who also come to visit. This is more appropriate for _chag ha'asif_, when there is bounty around.